# iphone: co-processor offset out of range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compilation

i have a strange compiling problem with xcode and iphone. my game is almost finish but now i got suddently this compiling error:

```
{standard input}:6108:co-processor offset out of range

gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

this only happens if i compile the release version for the device. the debug version and both versions for the simulator works. clean targets and recompile don't work.
strangly enough that error only happens if i add a line of code to one specific source file and only between these lines:

```
[_sharedDirector checkAndPutScoreToHighscore:(int)[player score]];
gameOverScreen = YES;
gameOverScreenSlideY = 320.0f;
[buttonManager activateButtonWithID:replayButton];
[buttonManager activateButtonWithID:menuButton];
```

so when i put a random line between this lines of code i get that error.
i do not know what causes this error. i had opened the sourcecode file to "show as assembly file" just for fun but i don't think this has caused the error.
has anybode a hint for me what could be going on? i am searching the web for over 3 hours and thats very frustrating.

Comment: Consider formatting your embedded code better it might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely found a compiler bug. You really should switch to the LLVM compiler (clang).