# Errors in CodeWarrior: co-processor offset out of range

Tags: c++, codewarrior

I'm trying to run a fuzzy inference system (FIS) application on a Freescale Kinetis K70F120M development board using CodeWarrior.

*I wrote an Interpreter software that reads two plain text files (one that contains a Fuzzy Model and the other with patterns to be recognized) and writes a C++ application that can be uploaded to a development board to operate based on data read by sensors.*

*All the information contained in the FIS C++ application is written by the Interpreter, there's no chance I miscalculated the dimensions of a vector because the amount of elements were counted from the data contained in the files.*

I've managed to run a FIS example application on the board but when I try to run the actual application I need to run I get the following  71 errors:

> **Description Resource    Path    Location    Type**
> C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s co-processor offset out of range
>    Prueba FALLAS 2
>         line 8696, external location: C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s
>   C/C++ Problem
> C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s co-processor offset out of range
>    Prueba FALLAS 2
>         line 8697, external location: C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s
>   C/C++ Problem
> ...
> C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s co-processor offset out of range
>    Prueba FALLAS 2
>         line 15897, external location: C:\Users\CRISTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLOvcxh.s
>  C/C++ Problem
> mingw32-make: *** [Sources/main.o] Error 1
>  Prueba FALLAS 2
>             C/C++ Problem

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
#include "derivative.h"
#include "network.h"

int main() {
Network ReporteDeFallasCEC;
const int NInputs = 50, NClasses = 10, NRules = 32;
ReporteDeFallasCEC.initialize();
ReporteDeFallasCEC.setClassNeurons(NClasses);
ReporteDeFallasCEC.setRuleNeurons(NRules, 0, Network::Pruning());

Universe input1;
input1.setLimits(0, 100);
input1.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vs", 0, 17.52, 35.04));
input1.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("s", 9.3, 29.65, 50));
input1.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("m", 23.82, 45.24, 66.67));
input1.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("l", 50, 66.67, 83.33));
input1.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vl", 66.67, 83.33, 100));
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addVariable(input1);

Universe input2;
input2.setLimits(0, 100);
input2.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vs", 0, 24.75, 49.51));
input2.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("s", 5.45, 27.72, 50));
input2.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("m", 33.33, 5, 6.67));
input2.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("l", 50, 66.67, 83.33));
input2.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vl", 66.67, 83.33, 100));
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addVariable(input2);

//...here goes the remaining "universe" objects

Universe input50;
input50.setLimits(0, 100);
input50.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vs", 0, 22.79, 45.57));
input50.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("s", 0, 34.55, 100));
input50.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("m", 20.59, 43.63, 66.67));
input50.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("l", 42.4, 68.49, 95.99));
input50.addFuzzySet(FuzzySet("vl", 66.67, 83.33, 100));
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addVariable(input50);

ClassNeuron InterferenciaDeGas;
ClassNeuron TuberiaDesancladaConGolpeDeFluido;
ClassNeuron RoturaDeVarilla;
ClassNeuron FugaEnLaValvulaFijaDePie;
ClassNeuron FugaEnLaValvulaViajera;
ClassNeuron BarrilDeLaBombaDoblado;
ClassNeuron BuenLlenadoConTuberiaAnclada;
ClassNeuron AgujeroEnElBarrilDeLaBomba;
ClassNeuron AnclaDeTuberiaEnMalFuncionamiento;
ClassNeuron BarrilDeLaBombaGastado;

RuleNeuron FLRule65248697 = RuleNeuron();
FLRule65248697.setNumInputsNeurons(NInputs);
FLRule65248697.setNumClasses(NClasses);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(0, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(1, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(2, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(3, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(4, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(5, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(6, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(7, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(8, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(9, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(10, 0);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(11, 2);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(12, 2);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(13, 3);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(14, 3);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(15, 3);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(16, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(17, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(18, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(19, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(20, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(21, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(22, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(23, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(24, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(25, 3);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(26, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(27, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(28, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(29, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(30, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(31, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(32, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(33, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(34, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(35, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(36, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(37, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(38, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(39, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(40, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(41, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(42, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(43, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(44, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(45, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(46, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(47, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(48, 4);
FLRule65248697.setAntecedent(49, 4);
FLRule65248697.setConsecuent(1);
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addRule(FLRule65248697);

RuleNeuron FLRule50510248 = RuleNeuron();
FLRule50510248.setNumInputsNeurons(NInputs);
FLRule50510248.setNumClasses(NClasses);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(0, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(1, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(2, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(3, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(4, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(5, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(6, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(7, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(8, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(9, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(10, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(11, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(12, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(13, 0);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(14, 2);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(15, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(16, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(17, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(18, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(19, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(20, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(21, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(22, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(23, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(24, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(25, 3);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(26, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(27, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(28, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(29, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(30, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(31, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(32, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(33, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(34, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(35, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(36, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(37, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(38, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(39, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(40, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(41, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(42, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(43, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(44, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(45, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(46, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(47, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(48, 4);
FLRule50510248.setAntecedent(49, 4);
FLRule50510248.setConsecuent(2);
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addRule(FLRule50510248);

//...here goes the remaining "RuleNeuron" objects

RuleNeuron FLRule2056998 = RuleNeuron();
FLRule2056998.setNumInputsNeurons(NInputs);
FLRule2056998.setNumClasses(NClasses);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(0, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(1, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(2, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(3, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(4, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(5, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(6, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(7, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(8, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(9, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(10, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(11, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(12, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(13, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(14, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(15, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(16, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(17, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(18, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(19, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(20, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(21, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(22, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(23, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(24, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(25, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(26, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(27, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(28, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(29, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(30, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(31, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(32, 0);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(33, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(34, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(35, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(36, 1);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(37, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(38, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(39, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(40, 2);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(41, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(42, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(43, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(44, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(45, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(46, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(47, 4);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(48, 3);
FLRule2056998.setAntecedent(49, 4);
FLRule2056998.setConsecuent(3);
ReporteDeFallasCEC.addRule(FLRule2056998);

const int nPatterns = 60;
double patternArray[nPatterns][NInputs] = {
{ 6.60, 9.70, 12.2, 4.60, 5.70, 8.70, 12.9, 7.60, 11.8, 7.90, 24.9, 44.3, 55.0, 63.6, 71.3, 75.0, 76.8, 80.9, 84.50, 86.50, 90.70, 91.40, 95.00, 97.30, 93.80, 69.20, 82.60, 95.80, 98.90, 97.20, 97.70, 97.80, 96.90, 97.50, 94.50, 93.50, 95.80, 92.50, 93.60, 94.20, 92.00, 90.20, 91.60, 90.20, 91.50, 91.80, 90.70, 93.90, 96.10, 95.70 },
{ 7.70, 5.50, 4.50, 0.60, 1.70, 5.90, 6.70, 6.70, 8.60, 10.1, 5.60, 5.30, 8.40, 24.3, 57.2, 79.8, 88.0, 90.8, 91.10, 91.90, 92.40, 91.80, 91.60, 91.40, 95.70, 62.20, 94.10, 96.40, 91.60, 92.40, 94.00, 97.40, 97.70, 97.80, 96.10, 94.40, 94.40, 96.00, 98.10, 99.30, 94.40, 94.50, 96.30, 96.80, 94.20, 94.50, 96.60, 98.70, 97.10, 97.30 },

//...here goes the remaining pattern rows

{ 1.95, 3.10, 2.00, 3.20, 1.90, 3.70, 5.70, 5.00, 2.10, 3.50, 3.30, 2.05, 2.95, 2.40, 2.70, 3.80, 4.10, 3.30, 4.700, 5.100, 5.300, 5.900, 8.600, 14.30, 38.70, 87.40, 94.80, 96.00, 97.00, 97.40, 98.40, 98.80, 98.10, 98.90, 96.50, 92.00, 83.80, 75.00, 67.80, 69.00, 77.00, 87.70, 94.90, 96.00, 95.80, 95.60, 95.70, 93.80, 87.60, 38.80 }, };

double pattern[NInputs];
for (int i = 0; i < nPatterns; i++) {
    std::cout << "Patron " << i + 1 << ": [ ";
    for (int j = 0; j < NInputs; j++) {
        pattern[j] = patternArray[i][j];
        std::cout << patternArray[i][j];
        if (j != NInputs - 1) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << " ]" << "\n";
    int clase = ReporteDeFallasCEC.classificate(pattern);
    std::cout << "\nClase [ " << clase << " ]\n\n";
}

//std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This CodeWarrior Project was created in the CodeWarrior IDE v.10.6.4 as a new Bareboard Project:
Device to be used: MK70FN1M0 processor (K70F 120 MHz Family)
Project Type: Application
Connection to be used: Open Source JTAG
Language: C++
Floating Point: Hardware (-mfloat-abi=hard) vs. (-fp vfpv4)
I/O Support: Debugger Console
ARM Build Tools: GCC
Rapid Application Development: None
Start with perspective designed for: current perspective

I'm building the project with the FLASH configuration and debugging as "Prueba FALLAS 2_FLASH_OSJTAG".
I'm running CodeWarrior on Windows 7.

Help me find what's preventing the code from running on the board.

**Update #1:**
I've removed the code concerning the generation of the "ClassNeuron" and "RuleNeuron" objects and the patternArray vector including the functions that make use of that vector, so the remaining application is only creating the 50 "Universe" objects. After doing that I proceeded to remove a deliberate number of Universe objects to try to find out if there is a memory limit related issue, but wether it is 15 or 26 objects, I get a random amount of errors of the type described above (even 0 errors).
I need to run my application with that exact quantity of objects (50 Universes, 10 Classes, 32 Rules & the 50x60 Pattern Array).

I suspect that the problem has something to do with the amount of objects the code creates, but I'm not sure if there is a FLASH memory limit set by CodeWarrior when the project is compiled. Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure that these errors have nothing to do with array handling, for I have enterely removed any reference to the patternArray from the project and, still, if I were doing something wrong with arrays, the CodeWarrior IDE should have given me some kind of clue on that.

Help me solve this problem as it is difficult to find info on this matter, even in the NXP(freescale) community.

**Update #2:**
As stated in the following related questions It appears that this error is actually a compiler bug, please confirm this to me:

- [cross-compilation FFTW for cortex-a15 failure: co-processor offset out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704069/cross-compilation-fftw-for-cortex-a15-failure-co-processor-offset-out-of-range)
- [iphone: co-processor offset out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918199/iphone-co-processor-offset-out-of-range)

This is my post at the NXP(formerly Freescale) Community: [co-processor offset out of range](https://community.freescale.com/message/630516)

---

#### Partially Solved

I moved my code to a project in Kinetis Design Studio. It compiled with no errors and I could debug the application until some point when the board ran out of memory, then I applied some optimization changes and everything went great.

Comment: Please just don't downvote this question, if this is not a "good" question tell me how can I make it better. I'm not a veteran programmer but neither a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Since it suggests it may have something to do with array sizes I'd recommend checking on your array initializations first.

The error `co-processor offset out of range` doesn't relate to any of your variables, but there's array variable: `double patternArray[nPatterns][NInputs]`. Do these have correct number of elements?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried commenting out the codeblocks where patternArray is defined and used, leaving only the creation and operation of the "universe", "classneuron" and "ruleneuron" objects and the quantity of errors stayed the same. I went further and commented the ruleneuron and classneuron definition lines and there were still errors (now down to 62). Finally I started commenting the universe objects one by one until reached Universe input 26, there the errors stopped happening.

Comment: @user3606929 glad you resolved your problem somehow. In all honesty, I'd expect the tools to be somewhat more of help. Good luck in the future.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, I didn't meant I had solved the problem, just that when I remove some of the universe objects the error stops to pop out. Now, I tried commenting all the universe objects and again no problems are shown. I'm really confused, the other project works just fine, I'm still waiting for an answer. :)

Comment: @crizart If you access an array out-of-bounds, the behavior of the program is undefined.   It may work sometimes and not other times.

Comment: Thank you for your response Paul. I figured out I need to expand my question with some extra details I had not in mind when I posted. This code was not written by myself but was generated by an interpreter software which reads a plain-text file that contains the pattern data, and then writes this cpp file with that info, so the patternArray boundaries are set by the amount of data (float decimal numbers) present in the text file. It's not a matter of a typo, as I mentioned before, even when I disable the patternArray lines of code by commenting them, errors show when I build the project.